# call write-file interactively with prompting

Tags: files, default, prompt, call-interactively

I have a function that creates a buffer, with a default file name, and would like the first user action for that buffer be a *prompt* to write the buffer to a file, allowing the user to change the default, but offering the default in the minibuffer prompt.

The best result of all the options I have tried so far does properly associate the desired filename and path with a buffer, and does prompt the user, but does not offer the default name as a default.

Here is one of the best versions of the test function:

```
(defun my-write-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let*
     ((name "foo.txt")
      (path "/home/me/foo.txt")
      (buf (create-file-buffer name)))
   (pop-to-buffer buf)
   (insert "random text\n")
   (set-visited-file-name path)
   (call-interactively 'write-file (vector path))))
```

My guess is that I am somehow not properly defining the vector argument to function `call-interactively`, but I could be wrong; Maybe I'm just using the wrong elisp function?

Comment: You may be interested in the function `read-file-name`, which can have default input, visible suggested initial input, etc. -- store the value to a let-bound variable and later pass that value to `write-file`.  I'm not sure why you would need `write-file` *interactively*, if you use `read-file-name`.  To see more about that function, type `M-x describe-function` or `C-h f`.  And, unless I am mistaken, `write-file` does not take a *vector* -- it takes a STRING as its first argument.  Again, describe the function `write-file` and see what the doc-string suggests for its arguments.

Comment: @lawlist - YES! I was playing with that when you wrote the comment, and am close to posting an answer to my own question, that includes `read-file-name`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the function now working to my satisfaction, as below, but am open to suggestions if I'm not doing things optimally. In the solution below, I use function `read-file-name` to prompt the user, and use `condition-case` to trap a user response of `C-g`, the `quit` signal, so that the default buffer file name is set for the buffer.

```
(defun my-write-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let*
     ((name "foo.txt")
      (dir "/home/me/")
      (buf (create-file-buffer name)))
   (pop-to-buffer buf)
   (insert "random text\n")
   (condition-case nil
     (progn ()
       (set-visited-file-name
         (expand-file-name
           (read-file-name "Save to: " dir nil nil name)))
       (save-buffer))
     (quit (set-visited-file-name name)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

*(This is more of a comment than an answer, but it required more space/formatting than a comment.)*

> `(call-interactively 'write-file (vector path))`
>
> My guess is that I am somehow not properly defining the vector argument to function `call-interactively`

You seem to have mis-read the `call-interactively` documentation.

You *can* pass a vector to `call-interactively`, but only to pass a sequence of keys/events, and even then it's not the second argument, but the third:

> ```
> (call-interactively FUNCTION &optional RECORD-FLAG KEYS)
> ```
>
> Call FUNCTION, providing args according to its interactive calling specs.
> Return the value FUNCTION returns.
> The function contains a specification of how to do the argument reading.
> In the case of user-defined functions, this is specified by placing a call
> to the function ‘interactive’ at the top level of the function body.
> See ‘interactive’.
>
> Optional second arg RECORD-FLAG non-nil
> means unconditionally put this command in the command-history.
> Otherwise, this is done only if an arg is read using the minibuffer.
>
> Optional third arg KEYS, if given, specifies the sequence of events to
> supply, as a vector, if the command inquires which events were used to
> invoke it.  If KEYS is omitted or nil, the return value of
> ‘this-command-keys-vector’ is used.

Comment: Thanks. I just now went back and tried another series of evaluations, but don't really understand how to use a vector of key events to pass a mandatory argument to a function that is evaluated using `called-interactively`, my example being function `write-file`. This kind of case (a function with a mandatory argument) doesn't seem like one that the emacs developers would have overlooked, so I'm still missing something fundamental.

Comment: Yes, the point is that you *can't* use the `call-interactively` arguments to pass arguments to the command being called.  That's not what they are for (as is indicated by the docstring I've quoted, which explains what they *are* for).  The whole point of `call-interactively` is that the command arguments are *not* passed directly, but instead obtained via the command's own `interactive` spec.

Comment: I'm honestly a bit perplexed as to how/where you got the impression that you could do what you were attempting.  I'm assuming it was just a guess on your part, in which case I highly recommend that you get into the habit of using `C-h f` to read the documentation of a function and learn what its arguments are for.

Comment: What is a series of keys events?

Comment: @DidierA. A `KEYS` value would typically be a vector of integers and/or symbols.  E.g. `[3 118]` (for the key sequence `C-c v`).  See `C-h i g (elisp) Input Events` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is all you're asking for.

```el
(defun my-write-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((name  "foo.txt")
        (dir   "~/drews-lisp-20/bbbbb/"))
    (pop-to-buffer (find-file-noselect (expand-file-name name dir)))
    (insert "random text\n")
    (write-file (read-file-name "Save as file: " dir name))))
```

Did I miss something?  The question is not too clear to me.

`find-file-noselect` is your friend.